# `sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `,'`

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, cygwin

I get the below error on running above command from shell script in CYGWIN.

Error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `,'

IF I ran command in cmd:

```
$ sed -n "8937,8946 p" "/cygdrive/c/TEMP/temp_oracle/alert_cert1_copy.log" | egrep -e "ORA-|Shutting down"
```

It works OK - Result:

```
ORA-1623 signalled during: ALTER DATABASE DROP LOGFILE GROUP 1...
Shutting down database
```

NOTE: `8937` & `8946` are the line numbers in text file - where it is needed to check the patterns. Searching must be between these lines.

IF I run the command in from shell script - the above error appears.

---

Shell Script:

```
    export alert_file="/cygdrive/c/TEMP/temp_oracle/alert_cert1_copy.log"
    export alert_output="/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/alert_out.log"

        function searchAlertByFilterLN() {
            #err1=$(sed -n "${lastLineNum},${totLines} p" $alert_file | egrep -e "ORA-")
            err1=$(sed -n "8937,8946 p" $alert_file | egrep -e "ORA-|Shutting down")
                if [ -n "$err1" ]; then  
                echo -e "Errors found:" > $alert_output
                echo ------------       >> $alert_output
                sed -n "8937,8946 p" $alert_file | egrep -e "ORA-|Shutting down" >> $alert_output
                echo "" >> $alert_output
                echo "" >> $alert_output
                echo -e "Check the details of the errors below. (Details means the surroundig lines of the error message only)" >> $alert_output
                echo  "-------------------------------------" >> $alert_output
                sed -n "8937,8946 p" $alert_file | /usr/bin/egrep -A 5 -B 2 "ORA-|Shutting down" >> $alert_output
                fi
        }

searchAlertByFilterLN --
echo "function was executed"
```

With regards!

Comment: Copy paste the contents of your script and how are you running the script?

Comment: don't make us guess, show you actual script code that fails. I bet that you are using `sed -n "$startLineNo,$endLineNo p" file` or similar and that either the vars are misspelled, or for some other reason one or both don't have values. Do you know about shell debug mode, with `set -vx` (and `set +vx` to turn off). This will show you the line as executed **with** variables replaced with their values. Good luck.

Comment: Also, please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Shelter, i have read a lot of questions not corresponding the policy of the site, so please.

Comment: @bulatmakhmutov: Can you change this line `sed -n "8937,8946 p" $alert_file` to `sed -n "8937,8946 p" "$alert_file"` with proper double-quotes areound `$alert_file`? Can you do that around all the instances in the script and try?

Comment: Indian, it works. Thanks

Comment: @bulatmakhmutov: Since you are relatively new here, read [What does it mean when an answer is accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Use proper double-quotes around variables in the script to avoid `shell` misinterpreting your forward-slashes(`/`), new-lines and word-splitting. All your variables used in your script are missing it.

The corrected version of your script should be something like

```
 #!/bin/bash

export alert_file="/cygdrive/c/TEMP/temp_oracle/alert_cert1_copy.log"
export alert_output="/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/alert_out.log"

function searchAlertByFilterLN() {
    #err1=$(sed -n "${lastLineNum},${totLines} p" $alert_file | egrep -e "ORA-")
    err1=$(sed -n "8937,8946 p" "$alert_file" | egrep -e "ORA-|Shutting down" )
     if [ -n "$err1" ]; then  
         echo -e "Errors found:" > "$alert_output"
         echo ------------       >> "$alert_output"
         sed -n "8937,8946 p" "$alert_file" | egrep -e "ORA-|Shutting down" >> $alert_output
         echo "" >> "$alert_output"
         echo "" >> "$alert_output"
         echo -e "Check the details of the errors below. (Details means the surroundig lines of the error message only)" >> "$alert_output"
         echo  "-------------------------------------" >> "$alert_output"
         sed -n "8937,8946 p" "$alert_file" | /usr/bin/egrep -A 5 -B 2 "ORA-|Shutting down" >> "$alert_output"
     fi
}

searchAlertByFilterLN --
```